# Can't destroy correctly object in Unity MLAPI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to destroy specific object on mouse1 click. I am using Unity MLAPI 0.1.0. When I spawn object (SpawnPuzzlePieceServerRpc), I save it's network id into a NetworkVariable. Object then follows mouse cursor (MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseServerRpc). After that, if I press mouse 1 button, I want that spawned object to be destroyed. Method (DeleteActivePuzzlePieceServerRpc) destroys object both on host and client, however, method continues to be called for some reason, and throws KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary. NetworkVariable (activePuzzlePieceNetId) seems to be updated to 0 (because of the error throwned constantly), so the method shouldn't be called again because of the condition in Update(). It feels like NetworkVariable is not syncing correctly here. What could be the problem and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

```
using UnityEngine;
using MLAPI;
using MLAPI.Messaging;
using MLAPI.Spawning;
using MLAPI.NetworkVariable;

public class PlayerTest : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform[] puzzlePiecePrefabs;
    NetworkVariable<ulong> activePuzzlePieceNetId = new NetworkVariable<ulong>(0);

    void Start()
    {
        activePuzzlePieceNetId.Settings.ReadPermission = NetworkVariablePermission.Everyone;
        activePuzzlePieceNetId.Settings.WritePermission = NetworkVariablePermission.Everyone;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsLocalPlayer) return;

        if (!activePuzzlePieceNetId.Value.Equals(0))
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            {
                DeleteActivePuzzlePieceServerRpc();
            }
            else
            {
                MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseServerRpc();
            }
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    void DeleteActivePuzzlePieceServerRpc()
    {
        NetworkObject puzzlePiece = NetworkSpawnManager.SpawnedObjects[activePuzzlePieceNetId.Value];
        Destroy(puzzlePiece.gameObject);
        activePuzzlePieceNetId.Value = 0;
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    public void SpawnPuzzlePieceServerRpc(int puzzlePieceId)
    {
        Transform puzzlePiece = Instantiate(puzzlePiecePrefabs[puzzlePieceId]);
        puzzlePiece.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().SpawnWithOwnership(OwnerClientId);
        activePuzzlePieceNetId.Value = puzzlePiece.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().NetworkObjectId;
        SpawnPuzzlePieceClientRpc();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void SpawnPuzzlePieceClientRpc()
    {
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    void MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseServerRpc()
    {      
        MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseClientRpc();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseClientRpc()
    {
        NetworkObject puzzlePiece = NetworkSpawnManager.SpawnedObjects[activePuzzlePieceNetId.Value];
        puzzlePiece.transform.position = GetMousePositionInWorld();
    }

    Vector3 GetMousePositionInWorld()
    {
        var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 19;
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseServerRpc()` is called in every frame where `!activePuzzlePieceNetId.Value.Equals(0)` and `!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)` ... Have you tried Debugging if your value is set correctly? Also note that either way there will be some delaye until the `0` actually resches you .. in the meantime **every client** is spamming the server with `MakeActivePuzzlePieceFollowMouseServerRpc()` every frame ...

Comment: It might be delay, because when debugging it shows correct value, so this shouldn't happen. I fixed it now by just adding try/catch block, and exiting function this way. I don't think it is alright to leave this way though.

Comment: Well in general it is not good at all to send an RPC **every frame**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `NetworkVariable`s in a script inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`. You should use it in a script inheriting from `NetworkBehaviour` and add the `NetworkObject` component to the game object to which script belongs. You have to first make sure this network object is spawned across the network in order to use `NetworkVariable`s inside it.

Actually, you don't need to use `NetworkVariable` to spawn and destroy objects across the network.

When you want to spawn a prefab, you can use a server RPC to spawn it on the server side

```
// Keep a reference to the prefab instance so you can destroy it later.
private NetworkObject m_PrefabInstance;

[ServerRpc]
private void SpawnPrefabServerRpc() 
{
    m_PrefabInstance = Instantiate(yourPrefab);
    prefabInstance.SpawnWithOwnership(OwnerClientId);
}
```

And when you want to destroy the prefab, you only need to destroy it on the server side and it will be destroyed on all clients automatically

```
[ServerRpc]
private void DestroyPrefabServerRpc()
{
    Destroy(m_PrefabInstance);
}
```